# My today extension's body is not showing swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios-app-extension

I've been writing a today widget. The extension has a title but the body is not showing.

[image]

I changed viewDidLoad method with this and added constraints to elements, still not working in simulator or device.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 250);
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not showing means there is something wrong with your code.
Need more context to solve this so try attaching your debugger.

One problem is that usually if you use Swift, you have to declare `@objc(TodayViewController)` above the class declaration file to enable the app to find the class.

Comment: I guess something is wrong with ios 8 beta. It works for every 1 of 3-4 trials without any change..